# How to limit number of rows passed to a called procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, collections, plsql, limit

One procedure is calling another procedure and passing a collection of numbers. I want to process all the records in the table but put a limit on number of rows processed in the second procedure in one go.

Below is my code.

```
create or replace procedure proc1
is
    emp_id dbms_sql.number_table;
begin
    select employee_id bulk collect into emp_id from employees;
    PROC2(EMP_ID);
end;
/
create or replace
procedure proc2(vin_emp_id dbms_sql.number_table)
is
begin
null;
END ;
```

Comment: How do you want to define that limit and are they the only records you will process or do you want to loop around until you've processed all the records ?

Comment: want  to loop all the records in proc2 but want to limit number of records being processed in proc2 in one go.

Comment: `create or replace procedure proc1
is
    emp_id dbms_sql.number_table;
    cursor c_emp is select employee_id from employees;
    v_limi number := 100;
begin
 open c_emp; 
 loop 
    fetch c_emp bulk collect into emp_id  limit v_limit;
    PROC2(EMP_ID); 
  exit when emp_id.count < v_limi;
  end loop;  
close c_emp;
end;
/`

Comment: @Pratik But i'm not sure that are you asking about this ?

Comment: So for example if proc1 captures 5,000 records in `emp_id`, you want to call proc2 five times passing 1,000 records at a time? You would have to write code to copy the data into smaller arrays as there is no syntax for referring to subsets of arrays (other than `forall`, which is no help here). It might be simplest and most efficient just to pass the full array together with the start and end for the range you want proc2 to process.

Answer (score 1):

> "want to limit number of records being processed in proc2 in one go"

The way to throttle the records processed in `proc2` is to submit batches. The PL/SQL `bulk collect` syntax supports a LIMIT clause. So, to pass batches of 100 records at a time you need to rewrite `proc1` like this:

```
create or replace procedure proc1
is
    emp_id dbms_sql.number_table;
    cursor emp_recs is
        select employee_id from employees
begin
    open emp_recs;
    loop
        fetch emp_recs bulk collect into emp_id limit 100;
        exit when emp_id.count() = 0;
        PROC2(EMP_ID);
    end loop;
    close emp_recs;
end;
/
```

Use the `emp_id.count()` syntax to check whether any records are found in the most recent fetch, and exit if none are. Don't test for `cursor%NOTFOUND` because that will be true if the number of records fetched is less than the limit amount, but we still want to call `proc2` even if the last batch has only one record.

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the rows selected into `emp_id`:

```
create or replace procedure proc1
is
    emp_id dbms_sql.number_table;
begin
    select employee_id
     bulk collect into emp_id from employees  where rownum <= 101;

    PROC2(EMP_ID);
end;
/
```